# iterating through hundreds of thousands of csv files with pandas

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

I am currently using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExectutor to iterate through a ton of CSV files like below:

```
def readcsv(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="\s+", names=[headers], comment="#")
    #DOING SOME OTHER STUFF TO IT 
    full.append(df) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    full = []
    files = "glob2 path to files" 
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=45) as proc:
        proc.map(readcsv,files)
    full = pd.concat(full)
```

This does not currently work in this fashion, as it returns a ValueError "No Objects to concatenate" on the last line. How can I iterate through the files and append them to a list and then concat them or just place them directly into a dataframe as fast as possible? Resources available are 64gb ram and 46 cores in a virtual machine.

Comment: Have you looked at [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) - it'll do this for you... `df = dask.dataframe.read_csv('*.csv').compute()`.... If you take off the compute, you can also do operations on it while reading and have it piece them together if you don't require *all* the data in memory at once and just want to sum a column etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` function actually [returns an iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) with the results from the functions. So you just need to return the `df`:

```
def readcsv(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="\s+", names=[headers], comment="#")
    #DOING SOME OTHER STUFF TO IT 
    return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = "glob2 path to files" 
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=45) as proc:
        full = pd.concat(proc.map(readcsv,files))
```